# Roll up sparse table in vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm using vertica.

**Problem:**
I have sparse table (user_session_tmp2). Row contains session_token and a list (about 15 fields) of params. Several rows can describe one session_token. I need to get table where only one row describes one session (i.e. merge all data for one session in one row)

Obvious solution is:

```
merge /*+ direct */ into user_session tgt using user_session_tmp2 src on src.session_token=tgt.session_token 
when matched then 
    update set time = (case when src.time> tgt.time then tgt.time else src.time)
               device_id = (case when src.device_id is not null then src.device_id else tgt.device_id) 
when not matched then 
    insert values(src.session_token, src.user_id, src.time, src.client_time, src.device_id, src.app_version, ... );
```

Unfortunately, it's not allowed to use case expression in update query.

Comment: `MERGE` is not the best approach. Could you update your question and add a small sample data set and the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the following solution:

```
    select session_token, max(col1), max(col2),.., max(colN) 
      from user_session
  group by session_token
```